# How to get docker image labels in runtime

Tags: docker

How to get docker image labels in runtime?

Or get `docker inspect image` info when the image instantiation is running .

thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible without giving the container access to the Docker socket, and through that unrestricted root-level access to the entire host.  You can set `ENV` variables in the Dockerfile that are very easy to retrieve, though, and that might be a better path.

Answer (score 0):

All the labels set in your dockerfile are visible on the container with the `docker container inspect` command.

You'll also find other informations such as `ENV` values, exposed ports, entrypoint, etc.